# Ace Code Editor - Code Folding in VBScript doesn't work if keyword isn't the first word on the line

Tags: ace-editor, folding

Code folding was recently added for VBScript for the Ace Code Editor which is great but I noticed an issue. If the keyword isn't the first word on the line, then folding doesn't work properly for the entire script.  For example:
This folds correctly:

Sub ThisisASubroutine()
End Sub

but this doesn't:

Protected Sub ThisisASubroutine()
End Sub